# H2O Exception: water.AutoBuffer.AutoBufferException

Tags: h2o

We are producitonalizing a model that was created using h2o. However, during one of our load tests, we are getting a 
`ERRR: water.AutoBuffer$AutoBufferException`

**What exactly is the AutoBufferException and what causes it to be thrown?**

Previously, when we deployed the application, we did not provide any Java heap memory parameters and during load testing, that always caused the instance to terminate due to an OOM error. However, since adding the Java heap memory parameter and conducting load tests, we have been getting the AutoBufferException under heavy load.

When we look at the Debug logs, we see that there is plenty of memory still available when this Exception is thrown. CPU usage seems to be pretty normal as well. Below is a snippet of our code and the stacktrace that the error produces.

According to the logs, h2o makes a series of web requests in order to complete the prediction. The exception only gets thrown during one of those calls: **(Request Type: POST, Request Path: /99/Models.bin)**. Once the exception gets thrown, the request fails and the service picks up the next request.

- h2o Version: 3.18.0.11
- Python Version: 3.5.4
- OS: RHEL 7.x

```py
h2o.connect(ip = HOST, port = PORT)
loaded_model = h2o.load_model(MODEL_PATH)

def predict(to_be_scored):
    to_be_scored_hex = h2o.H2OFrame(to_be_scored)
    prediction = loaded_model.predict(to_be_scored_hex)
    return prediction
```

We would expect the code to return a prediction, however the following stacktrace is the output.

```
Stacktrace: [water.AutoBuffer$AutoBufferException,
water.AutoBuffer.getImpl(AutoBuffer.java:634),
water.AutoBuffer.getSp(AutoBuffer.java:610),
water.AutoBuffer.get1(AutoBuffer.java:749),
water.AutoBuffer.get1U(AutoBuffer.java:750),
water.AutoBuffer.getInt(AutoBuffer.java:829),
water.AutoBuffer.get(AutoBuffer.java:793),
water.AutoBuffer.getKey(AutoBuffer.java:811),
water.AutoBuffer.getKey(AutoBuffer.java:808),
hex.Model.readAll_impl(Model.java:1635),
hex.tree.SharedTreeModel.readAll_impl(SharedTreeModel.java:411),
water.AutoBuffer.getKey(AutoBuffer.java:814),
water.Keyed.readAll(Keyed.java:50),
hex.Model.importBinaryModel(Model.java:2256),
water.api.ModelsHandler.importModel(ModelsHandler.java:209),
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63),
water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:451),
water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:296),
water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:222),
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755),
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848),
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684),
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086),
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116),
water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:197),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043),
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865),
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72),
org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264),
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608),
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543),
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)];parms={dir=/opt/h2o/data/model, model_id=}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could post the solution to your issue that you found. thanks!